# if 2 criteria hold, are unions of finitely many sets always expressible as a disjoint union of finitely many sets?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, general-topology, analysis, measure-theory

a set $R$ of subsets of some arbitrary set $X$, is defined to be generalised rectangles if for any $A,B\in R$

(a) we can express $A \setminus B$ as a disjoint union of finitely many elements of $R$

and

(b) that $A \cap B$ is also in $R$.

My question is whether we can drop the word "disjoint",

more precisely, define a set $R$ to be proto rectangles if $R$ is a set of subsets of some arbitrary set $X$, where for any $A, B \in R$ we have that $A \setminus B$ is a union of finitely many elements of $R$, not necessarily disjoint, ie can overlap arbitrarily, and that $A \cap B$ is also in $R$, is $R$ in fact generalised rectangles?

ie for every $A,B \in R$ is $A\setminus B$ in fact a disjoint union of finitely many sets from $R$?

(by assumption it is a possibly overlapping union of finitely many elements of $R$)

background to the question:

define a "semi-open" rectangle to be eg $\{ (x,y) : a1 \le x \lt a2, b1\le y \lt b2 \}$, where $a1, a2, b1, b2$ are real numbers,

then if $A$ and $B$ are semi-open rectangles, it is easy to see that the set minus $A\setminus B$ is a disjoint union of finitely many semi-open rectangles.  Also $A \cap B$ is semi-open.

The above generalised rectangles are sets of subsets satisfying these 2 criteria.

I personally think its probably not true in general, ie a set of proto rectangles isnt always a set of generalised rectangles.

which amounts to showing a counterexample, but I have spent a lot of time without being able to either prove or supply a counterexample. When I tried to prove it, I was heading to ideas which looked like Zorn's lemma, where potentially its a disjoint union of infinitely many, but I didnt have enough info to apply Zorn.

if you can prove $A \setminus B$ is a disjoint union of infinitely many elements of $R$, that would also be good.

what I have been able to show is that if $A_i \in R$ then if $\bigcup_1^n A_i$ is finite, it can be re-expressed as a disjoint union of finitely many elements of $R$.

the way I show this is to consider $S$ defined to be the set of unions of finitely many elements of $R$.

it is easy to show that if $U,V \in S$ then $U \setminus V \in S$, and $U \cap V \in S$.

ie $S$ is closed under setminus and intersection and union of pairs of elements of $S$, its definitely not always closed under infinite intersections and infinite unions as the set $R$ of semi-open rectangles furnishes counterexamples via its set $S$, as a point set and an open rectangle are respective counterexamples.

if an element $C$ of $S$ cannot be expressed as a disjoint union of finitely many elements of $R$,

$C$ is by assumption, an overlapping union of finitely many elements of $R$, say $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup ... \cup A_n$
where $n \ge 2 $, where let us assume $n$ is minimal, which means $n \ge 2$.

but if $B_i$ is $A_i \setminus \bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1}A_j$, then these $B_i$ also are in $S$,

$C = A_1 \cup B_2 \cup B_3 .... \cup B_n$ is a DISJOINT union of nonempty elements of $S$

Then at least one of the $B_i$ sets is also not a disjoint union of finitely many elements of $R$,
otherwise we have a contradiction if all are disjoint unions of finitely many.

thus if $C \in S$ cannot be expressed as a disjoint union of finitely many elements of $R$,
then $\exists D \in S$ where $D \subsetneq C$.
(eg $D$ is the first $B_i$ which cannot be expressed as a disjoint union of finitely many)

which means that if $C$ is finite, we get infinite descent, a contradiction.

and eg if $A,B \in R$ with $A\setminus B$ finite, then $A\setminus B$ IS a disjoint union of finitely many elements of $R$.

the question is what happens where $A \setminus B$ is infinite, either one needs to supply a counterexample, or to prove that this is also a disjoint union of finitely many elements of $R$.

a counterexample would need to involve infinite sets,

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to answer my own question,

let $X=[0,1]$ the interval, and let $R$ be the following sets:

$[0,a)$ and $(a,1]$ where $0<a<1$,
and also the sets $(c,d), (c,d], [c,d)$ where $0 < c < d < 1$,

where $[$ and $]$ mean we include the endpoint of the interval,
and $($ and $)$ mean we exclude the endpoint, eg $(c,d]=\{ x : c < x <= d \}$

it is easy to show that $R$ is closed under intersection by examining the different cases. Also its easy to show that setminus is expressible as a finite overlapping union, by examining the different cases.

Now consider the following setminus $[0,a) \setminus (b,1]=[0,b]$ where
$0< b < a <1$. this is an overlapping union, namely $[0,b]=[0,c) \cup (e,b]$
where $c$ and $e$ are any numbers satisfying $0<e<c<b$.

Assume $[0,b]$ can be expressed as a finite disjoint union of elements of $X$,
and take one with minimal number of sets:

$[0,b]=A_1 \cup A_2 \cup .... \cup A_n$,

where as each $A_i$ is an interval, we can arrange them in linear order,
and $n$ is minimum possible and $n>=2$ as $[0,b]$ isnt in $X$.

but the right bound of $A_n$ must be 1, thus $A_n=(f,1]$ for some $f$,

but this means that $[0,f]=[0,b]\setminus (f,1]=(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup ... \cup A_n) \setminus A_n=A_1 \cup A_2 \cup ... \cup A_{n-1}$

as its a disjoint union by assumption.

but if we rescale this all by a factor of $b/f$, and set $B_i = A_i * b/f$,

we get $[0,b]=B_1 \cup B_2 \cup .... \cup B_{n-1}$

a disjoint union of $n-1$ elements of $X$, contradicting the minimality of $n$,

thus $[0,b]$ cannot be expressed as a disjoint union of finitely many elements of $X$.

and thus we have a counterexample, where $X$ is proto rectangles but isnt generalised rectangles.

but the theorem is true for finite sets, ie a finite set which is an overlapping union of finitely many sets from some proto rectangles is always a disjoint union of finitely many such sets as explained in my original question.

I can in fact show that $[0,b]$ cannot be expressed as an arbitrary disjoint union of elements of $X$, which then shows the later conjecture is false that maybe the setminuses are disjoint unions of infinitely many elements of $X$.

the proof is like this: say $[0,b]=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$, some arbitrary union indexed by the set $I$.

Now $0 \in [0,b]$ thus $0$ is in one of the $A_i$ say $A$ this must be of the form $A=[0,g)$, and $b$ must be in one of the $A_i$ say $B$ which must be of the form $B=(h,b]$, and clearly $g<h$.

if we now take the union $U$ of all the $A_i$ of the form $(p,q]$, $U$ must lie to the right of $A$, and is nonempty as $B$ is a subset, thus it has an infimum $r$, where $0<g<=r<=h<b$. Thus $r \in [0,b]$, and so $r$ must be in one of the $A_i$ say in $C$,

consider the cases for $C$:

1. if $C=(s,t)$ or $C=[s,t)$, then $r < t$ and $t$ is also a lower bound, thus $r$ isnt the infimum, a contradiction.
2. if $C=(s,t]$, then in fact $C$ is part of the union $U$, and as an infimum $r <= C$, ie $r <= s$, but then $r$ cannot be in $C$, a contradiction.

thus whatever happens we get a contradiction, and so $[0,b]$ cannot be expressed as an arbitrary disjoint union of the elements of $X$.

Note that if we disregard the end points, the elements of $X$ are in fact the 1 dimensional subrectangles of $[0,1]$. thus the terminology of proto rectangles is apt for this example.